# Why does AWS Auto Scaling launch multiple instances during scaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I'm trying to set up an AWS Auto Scaling Group (ASG) that auto-scales based on average group CPU load.

I have a scale up policy that is supposed to scale the group up by 1 instance once the average CPU usage is higher than 70%. However when the alarm is triggered, the ASG launches several instances at the same time, which it shouldn'd do.

The relevant bits of CloudFormation configuration:

```
ECSScaleUpPolicy:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy
    Properties:
        AdjustmentType: "ChangeInCapacity"
        AutoScalingGroupName: !Ref ECSAutoScalingGroup
        PolicyType: "StepScaling"
        MetricAggregationType: "Average"
        EstimatedInstanceWarmup: 600
        StepAdjustments:
            -
                MetricIntervalLowerBound: "0"
                ScalingAdjustment: "1"

ECSScaleUpAlarm:
    Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
    Properties:
        AlarmDescription: "CPU more than 70% during the last minute."
        AlarmName: "ECSScaleUpAlarm"
        AlarmActions:
            -
                !Ref ECSScaleUpPolicy
        Dimensions:
            -
                Name: "ClusterName"
                Value: !Ref ECSCluster
        MetricName: "CPUReservation"
        Namespace: "AWS/ECS"
        ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
        Statistic: "Average"
        Threshold: 70
        Period: 60
        EvaluationPeriods: 1
        TreatMissingData: "notBreaching"
```

As you can see, the scaling adjustment is just 1 and the instance warmup is quite long, it should wait for more time before launching the second instance :(

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scale-based-on-demand.html#as-scaling-types) Policy type of `Step scaling` causes the group capacity to increase or decrease based on the size of the alarm breach. You need to change that to `Simple scaling` so that the capacity can be set based on a single adjustment.

Comment: It doesn't seem so:

```Simple scaling: execute policy when: ECSScaleUpAlarm breaches the alarm threshold: CPUReservation >= 70 for 3 consecutive periods of 60 seconds for the metric dimensions. Take the action: Add 1 instances And then wait: 200 seconds before allowing another scaling activity```

And yet, 2 instances launched immediately.